# Paginação com recycleview e staggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, paginação, android-recyclerview

Estou tentando fazer a paginação com Recycleview e StaggeredGridLayoutManager mas não estou obtendo o resultado correto.
Toda vez que inicio o app, logo no inicio da lista, ele exibe o toast que eu coloquei na função "onLoad" que seria pra ser chamado no final da lista, e fica infinitamente chamando essa função.

Estou usando essa biblioteca: https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate

Aqui está o codigo do Fragment:

```
public class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
public ArrayList<String> opcoes;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager;
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
public NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
private AdView mAdView;
public SolventRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = null;
public List<ImagemObjeto> imgs;

public int pagina = 1;
public Paginate.Callbacks callbacks;
public boolean isLoading = false;

private static final int GRID_SPAN = 2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.content_main, container, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();


    progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progresbar);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this.getContext());
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    mAdView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    nestedScrollView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nested_primeiro);

    gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);

    //Executo a chamada pela primeira vez
    AsyncTaskConsumirApi async = new AsyncTaskConsumirApi();
    async.execute();


    callbacks = new Paginate.Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "final da lista pagina "+pagina, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isLoading = true;
            AsyncTaskConsumirApi async = new AsyncTaskConsumirApi();
            async.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            // Indicate whether new page loading is in progress or not
            return isLoading;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasLoadedAllItems() {
            // Indicate whether all data (pages) are loaded or not
            return false;
        }
    };
    return rootView;
}


public static DemoObjectFragment newInstance(int position) {
    DemoObjectFragment f = new DemoObjectFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_OBJECT, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

public class AsyncTaskConsumirApi extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<ImagemObjeto>> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //To show ProgressBar
}

@Override
protected List<ImagemObjeto> doInBackground(String[] strings) {
    ControllerApi controllerApi = new ControllerApi(getContext(), "");
    String json = controllerApi.pegarDados("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
    List<ImagemObjeto> novasImgs = controllerApi.baixarImagens(json, pagina);
    return novasImgs;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<ImagemObjeto> o) {
    super.onPostExecute(o);
    if (pagina==1) {
        imgs = o;
        adapter = new SolventRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), imgs);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Paginate.with(recyclerView, callbacks)
                .setLoadingTriggerThreshold(2)
                .addLoadingListItem(true)
                .setLoadingListItemSpanSizeLookup(new LoadingListItemSpanLookup() {
                    @Override
                    public int getSpanSize() {
                        return GRID_SPAN;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    } else {
        for(int i =0;i<o.size();i++){
            imgs.add(o.get(i));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    pagina++;
    isLoading=false;
}}}
```

Aqui meu layout da fragment:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progresbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nested_primeiro"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fillViewport="true">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi, removi o nestedscrollview do meu xml, o [rycleview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) já implementa essa classe e colocar um recycleview dentro de do nestedscrollview resulta em bugs como esses.